# Como buscar dados de uma terceira tabela com base na tabela associativa

Tags: mysql, sql

**Para contextualizar:**
Tenho uma tabela chamada diretor e uma outra chamada escola. Existem escolas que diretores que estão cadastrados com o nome da escola. No caso, essas escolas estão cadastradas na tabela escola e a associação entre diretor e escola é feita por uma tabela associativa escola_diretor. Aonde eu pego o id dos dois e formo a associação na tabela.

**Dúvida:** 
Como eu atualizo na tabela escola os emails das respectivas escolas (diretores com nomes das escolas) que estão na tabela diretores? Os id's não são os mesmos e o nome também não está escrito da mesma forma em ambas as tabelas. Só tenho a tabela associativa como suporte para isso.

**Estrutura das tabelas:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `diretor` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `diretor_escola` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idDiretor` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `idEscola` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idDiretor_idEscola` (`idDiretor`,`idEscola`),
  CONSTRAINT `idDiretor` FOREIGN KEY (`idDiretor`) REFERENCES `diretor` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_idEscola` FOREIGN KEY (`idEscola`) REFERENCES `escola` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `escola` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `codigo` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(250) NOT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: É interessante se vocês colocar na sua pergunta a estrutura das tabelas.

Comment: Acrescentei as estruturas!

Comment: Ajustei minha resposta

Answer (score 2):

Basicamente você utilizará as chaves das tabelas para vinculá-las. Montei um exemplo sem saber o nome das colunas, mas é algo do tipo:

```
UPDATE e
   SET e.email = d.email
  FROM escola e
       INNER JOIN escola_diretor ed ON ed.idEscola = e.id
       INNER JOIN diretor d ON d.id= ed.idDiretor
```